# Linear dependence of three functions: $f(x) = \sin(x)$, $g(x) = \cos(x)$ and $h(x)=x$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} $ be a vector-space of functions $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$.
>   The following functions in the vector space are defined as follows:
>   $$f(x) = \sin(x),\qquad g(x) = \cos(x),\qquad h(x) = x.$$
>   Is the triple $(f,g,h)$ linearly dependent?

I have a feeling it is, because $h(x)$ is the identity function, so $h(\sin(x)) = \sin(x)$, and I know the definitions, I can't figure out how to put my explanation (if it is correct) properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linear dependent means there are coefficients $a,b,c$ (not all equal to zero) such that $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)+cx=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $h(x)$ is not the identity function when the operation is function addition, $f(x) = 0$ is. Function composition does not form a vector space, so linear dependence is as defined in the above comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your feeling is not correct. Recall that, by definition, if such functions are [linearly dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) then there are real numbers $A,B,C$ not all zero such that
$$A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)+Cx=0 \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$$
Now by letting $x=0,\pi/2,\pi$, we have three linear equations
$$\begin{cases}
A\cdot 0+B\cdot 1+C\cdot 0=0\qquad &(x=0)\\
A\cdot 1+B\cdot 0+C\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}=0\qquad &(x=\frac{\pi}{2})\\
A\cdot 0+B\cdot (-1)+C\cdot \pi=0\qquad &(x=\pi)\\
\end{cases}$$
What may we conclude about $A,B,C$? Can you take it from here?

Comment: @caverac What do you mean? OP is interested in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, so the domain for $x$ is the whole real line.

Comment: You mean "your feeling is incorrect", right?

Comment: @PedroA Yes, you are right, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Yes, but I realize issue is with my approach

Comment: @RobertZ that we ultimately get that A=B=C=0 for all cases?

Comment: Yes, the unique solution of the system is $A=B=C=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Asserting that $\{f,g,h\}$ is linearly independent means that$$(\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}):af+bg+ch=0\implies a=b=c=0.$$If $af+bg+ch=0$, then $af(0)+bg(0)+ch(0)=0$, which means that $b=0$. You still have $af+ch=0$. But then $af\left(\frac\pi2\right)+c\frac\pi2=0$, which means that $a+c\frac\pi2=0$, and $af(\pi)+ch(\pi)=0$, which means that $c\pi=0$. So, $a=c=0$ too.